# how to hide jQuery Dropdown Check List after calling another event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm facing a problem. I've a select box. Lets there are three option: No, Skip, Yes. If click on the "Yes", a new div will be appeared which have multiselect box for which I've used [this plugin](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html)

So, I write HTML like this:

```
<select class="man-catagory">
     <option value="no">No</option>
     <option value="skip">Skip</option>
     <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<div class="selection-content">
    <p class="left">Selection</p>
    <div class="left selection">
        <select class="multiple-select" multiple="multiple">
             <option>A</option>
             <option>B & C</option>
             <option>D & F</option>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and set `.selection-content { display: none; }`

then add jQuery

```
$('.man-catagory').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'yes') 
        $('.selection-content').slideDown();
    else {
        $('.selection-content').slideUp();
});
$(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist();
```

But, unfortunately, the dropdown of multiselect box didn't come when `.selection-content` appeared by selecting "Yes" at my local file. But, it came when I put those code at jsfiddle. May be, at my local files, the version of jquery is different. Anyway, I need to work that multiselect at my local files not jsfiddle. So, I arrange my code like this way:

```
$('.man-catagory').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
      $('.selection-content').slideDown();

      $(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist();

   } else {
      $('.selection-content').slideUp();
   }
});
```

At that time, it's started working at my local files. But, it created a new problem. If anybody click "Yes", `.selection-content` will appear with the multiselect box. Everything works perfectly at this stage. After that, if select "No"/"Skip", `.selection-content` will disappear with the multiselect box. It's okay too. But, after that if clicking again at "Yes", `.selection-content` will appear with two multiselect boxes!
[image]

If this process is repeated again, at third time there will be 3 multi-select boxes. At fourth time, it'll be four multiselect boxes! So, I think as I called that multiselect box at **if function**:

```
if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
   $('.selection-content').slideDown();
   $(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist();
}
```

I've to call something opposite of `$(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist();` at **else function**. What should I write at there?

I've written at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cydgdad0/1/) like my local files. Please, don't give me a solution calling multiselect box outside of `change() function`. This will be worked at jsfiddle but not at my local files for some unknown reason-I told once. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling something opposite of `$(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist();`, you could simply use a class (e.g., `dropdownchecklistactivated`) to determine whether it's been called or not.

Change

```
$(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist({
```

To

```
$(".multiple-select").not(".dropdownchecklistactivated").addClass("dropdownchecklistactivated").dropdownchecklist({
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cydgdad0/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you're reinitializing your plugin each time you change select box, sou you need to initialze it outside of your `change()` function:

```
 $(".multiple-select").dropdownchecklist({ 
        firstItemChecksAll: true, 
        textFormatFunction: function(options) {
            var selectedOptions = options.filter(":selected");
            var countOfSelected = selectedOptions.size();
            var size = options.size();
            switch(countOfSelected) {
               case 0: return "<i>Nobody<i>";
               case 1: return selectedOptions.text();
               case options.size(): return "<b>Everybody</b>";
               default: return countOfSelected + " People";
            }
        } 
    });    

 $('.man-catagory').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
        $('.selection-content').slideDown();



   } else {
       $('.selection-content').slideUp().hide();
   }
 });
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cydgdad0/3/)

Comment: Normally I'd completely agree with you, but the question specifically asks `Please, don't give me a solution calling multiselect box outside of change() function.`